# Pandas Create Variability DF with Multiple Row Averages in Different DF

Tags: pandas, variables, element, calculated-columns

I've been trying to create a column of variability given the mean of the column data values for 'A' and 'B' below. I don't understand how to create the average for each row or element-wise in the panda column by the single data value with the long-term average(s). For example, imagine if have data that looks like this in pandas df1:

```
Year     Name   Data
1999     A      2
2000     A      4
1999     B      6
2000     B      8
```

And, i have a DF with the long-term mean called "LTmean", which in this case is = 3 and 7.

```
mean_df = 
Name    Data mean
0   A          3
1   B          7
```

So, the result would look like this for a new df:   dfnew['var'] = (df1.['Data']/mean_df(???) -1:

```
Year   Name   Var
1999    A     -0.3
2000    A      0.3
1999    B     -0.14
2000    B      0.14
```

Thank you for any suggestions on this! Would a loop be the best idea to loop through each column by the "Name' in each DF somehow?

Comment: `df['Var'] = df1['Data']/LTmean - 1`?

Comment: yeah, i knew it had to be easy. I just needed to define the new dataframe "df" first with column names and it works now in my code. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Var'] = df1['Data']/LTmean - 1
```

Comment: hi - i've edited my question to a slightly more complex case. do you have a moment to answer?